# Moving panel with directshow video renderer in it

Tags: c#, panel, directshow

I have a few panels with different directshow IVideoWindow handles bound to them so that the videos get shown inside the panels (WindowStyle properties are: Child,ClipSiblings,ClipChildren,Caption) Now I would like to move these panels around but I can only manage to move them when the video content is not filling the entire panel and I'm clicking+holding mouse button on the empty panel space. I can move the video windows around in the panels but of course they only move inside their respective panel space.

Is there a way to bind the video window content directly to the panel , for example the entire panel with content moves freely around when I click+hold the videowindow menu bar?

Thanks in advance.

Forgot to mention,this is in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it finally and I can't believe how silly I was. I left out the

hr = videoWindow.put_MessageDrain(hWin.Handle);

line , of course the videowindow wouldnt "listen" to the panel.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Video Mixing Renderer 9 and have it tied to a user control. I have set the VMR9 to Windowless mode and then set the video clipping window on the IVMRWindowlessControl9 interface to the handle of my user control.  I also set the video to fill the panel completely, using IVMRWindowlessControl9.GetNativeVideoSize, IVMRWindowlessControl9.SetAspectRatioMode, and IVMRWindowlessControl9.SetVideoPosition whenever the panel gets resized. When the form that contains my user control gets moved around, the video follows along. This is all done with C# and DirectShow.NET.

Edited to add sample code:

```
public partial class VideoPanel : UserControl
{
    private VideoMixingRenderer9 _renderer;
    private IVMRWindowlessControl9 _windowlessControl;

    public VideoMixingRenderer9 Renderer
    {
        get
        {
            return _renderer;
        }
        set
        {
            _renderer = value;
            if (_renderer != null)
            {
                var filterConfig = _renderer as IVMRFilterConfig9;
                if (filterConfig != null)
                {
                    filterConfig.SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode.Windowless);
                    _windowlessControl = _renderer as IVMRWindowlessControl9;
                    if (_windowlessControl != null)
                    {
                        _windowlessControl.SetVideoClippingWindow(Handle);
                        SetSize();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetSize()
    {
        var srcRect = new DsRect();
        var dstRect = new DsRect(ClientRectangle);
        int arWidth, arHeight;
        _windowlessControl.GetNativeVideoSize(out srcRect.right, out srcRect.bottom, out arWidth, out arHeight);
        _windowlessControl.SetAspectRatioMode(VMR9AspectRatioMode.LetterBox);
        _windowlessControl.SetVideoPosition(srcRect, dstRect);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post a small code snippet about this? I only started with software development recently and would appreciate the extra help. .)

Comment: Thank you for the code. Tried to do the same with default video renderers and IVideoWindows but still can only move the videowindows inside the panels and not together with them although the handles and owner rights are set to them.